# Screen is flickering on max resolution

Tags: 13.04, resolution, intel-graphics, xrandr

I got a new pc with an Intel i7 4770 with no extra video card. So this pc uses the Intel HD 4600. My monitor is one from Dell. It's the U2711. The max resolution of the monitor is 2560x1440. To connect the pc to the monitor i am using a dual link DVI cable. Thats for the setup.

At first i cant get full resolution through the gui. The option 2560x1440 is not shown. But i found this script

```
xrandr | grep maximum &
sleep 2
gtf 2560 1440 60.0 &
sleep 2
xrandr --newmode "2560x1440_60.00" 311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync &
sleep 2
xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440_60.00 &
sleep 2
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440_60.00 &
exit 0
```

The script will change the resolution successfully. But after a while (~30 secs) the monitor starts turning black and back on. Its flickering. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: My guess is that option was blocked for a reason. Try at least getting HDMI cable for it. May be replacing all 60s in your script with 59 will help.

Comment: As far as i know DVI dual link is even better for this as HDMI. I tried HDMI so. Didn't work either. Yesterday i could swear i tried this script with 59 and it wouldn't work. After your comment i tried it again. After about 30 minutes still no flickering. Seems to work. Thank you.

Comment: What is better on Win is not what is better on Lin.

Comment: And now the flickering is back =(

Comment: @DocMeissner Remember that if you find a solution, create a new *answer*, don't tell us that you solved an issue in a *comment*.

Comment: @Lucio Thank you. I will keep this in mind. But for now it turns out the solution suggested by Barafu isn't one. Still flickering.

Comment: My new guess is this has something to do with the automatic regulation of the iGPU. Similar to this problem: http://www.ubuntusolutions.org/2009/02/screen-flickering-with-nvidia-on-ubuntu.html Have to investigate.

Comment: I did try turn of some automatic regulation in the bios but it showed no effect on the flickering. Then i read about the new kernel 3.10 and it's new drivers and function etc. So i installed one of the daily iso's of ubuntu 13.10. Since then the flickering is gone. Two days now after installation. But the option for 2560x1440 is still not available. Have to use the script from above to get full resolution. I will test this some more days before i mark it as the answer.

Comment: It's flickering again. 13.10 didn't solve this.

Comment: I guess i narrowed it down. The screen only starts flickering on HTML5 or flash content like youtube. It's enough to have a tab in Firefox with a youtube video in it but not visible. Firefox needs to be on top so. Has this something to do with the hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my motherboard wasn't capable of doing 2560x1440 over the DVI port. Only over HDMI but that wasn't alright for my monitor. Ended up buying a new video card.